# Configure that Newtonsoft serializer serializes a date respecting the local time

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I send javascript dates to the server via:

```
let start = new Date().toISOString()
```

This date string is sent as `UTC` date string.

On server side I have convert this utc date everywhere to the local date (CH/DE/AT) via `myDate.ToLocalTime()` which I want to save in the database.

I do not want this manual conversion at many places.

How can I fix this with newtonsoft json serializer ?

That I get always the current local time I do:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

in my Startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the below in your `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(o =>
    {
        o.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
    }
```

See [DateTimeZoneHandling setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm).
The [DateTimeZoneHandling Enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateTimeZoneHandling.htm) defines `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` as follows:

> **Local** - Treat as local time. If the DateTime object represents a
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), it is converted to the local time.